# Delayed Function Call

Tags: c++, asynchronous, c++11, function-calls, delayed-execution

What's the most elegant way of performing a delayed (and therefore also asynchronous) functional call using C++11, lambdas and async? Suggested naming: `delayed_async`. Reason for asking is that I want a GUI alert light to be switched off after given time (in this case one second) without blocking the main (wxWidgets main loop) thread of course. I've use wxWidgets' `wxTimer` for this and I find `wxTimer` rather cumbersome to use in this case. So that got my curious about how much more convenient this could be implemented if I instead used C++11's `async`<sup>[1](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/doc/headers/future/async.html), [2](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async)</sup>. I'm aware of that I need to protect the resources involved with mutexes, when using `async`.

Comment: What is this question about...?

Comment: You should really explain what you're trying to do. And *try it*.

Comment: delayed execution is not really related to asynchronous execution.

Comment: Just from reading the question, I would suggest `boost::asio`.

Comment: @Nordlöw: Because your question is poorly specified.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I've tried to make it more specific and describe it the context of one of my work projects.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/179891)

Comment: Put your calls to a queue that is processed by separate worker thread(s)? Or do you mean TIMED execution, that will apply after a certain point in time has been reached (relative or absolute)? You are really a bit unclear about the 'delayed' semantics.

Answer (score 12):

You mean something like this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <future>

int main()
{
    // Use async to launch a function (lambda) in parallel
    std::async(std::launch::async, [] () {
        // Use sleep_for to wait specified time (or sleep_until).
        std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds{1});
        // Do whatever you want.
        std::cout << "Lights out!" << std::endl;
    } );
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds{2});
    std::cout << "Finished" << std::endl;
}
```

Just make sure that you don't capture a variable by reference in the lambda.

Comment: This starts a new dedicated thread (or uses some pool thread) and this thread will be blocked by the sleep.