# Asynchronous C++ WaitForSeconds function with parameters

Tags: c++, asynchronous

After a login my program needs to wait 4 seconds and check if the player is still logged in before writing score. I call the function as a asynchronous one:

```
std::async (scoreAttendance, p); //p = pointer to player
```

This is my function:

```cpp
void scoreAttendance(player *p)
{
    time_t beginT = time(NULL);
    time_t   endT = time(NULL);
    while(difftime(endT, beginT) < p->attendingTime){
        endT = time(NULL);}
    if (p->user != NULL){
        sendScore(saveScore);}
}
```

But it's not doing it asynchronous, it's blocking the whole program for 4 seconds. What did I do wrong?

---

Additional Informations:
The program is running on a game server. If a connected RFID Listener reads a new RFID it informs the game server about this login via TCP/IP. The received data is processed in a LoginFunction that calls the async scoreAttendance():

```cpp
//TCP Server handles the received data
void session::handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
                          size_t bytes_transferred)
{
  [...]
  std::vector<char> response =
               packet.process(data_, bytes_transferred, ip);
  [...]
}

//This leads to the process function
void process(datapacket& gamedata)
{
  std::string command = gamedata.getvalue("command");
  PROCESS_COMMAND(u,"plug/rfid/read", loginStation);
  [...]
}

//process calls this login function
void loginStation(datapacket& gamedata)
{
   [...]
   //Identifies the User by his RFID
   [...]
   std::async (scoreAttendance, p);
   return;
}
```

Comment: At the moment your question does not give enough info to diagnose the problem. Could you add some context around where you are calling std::async? Showing us the problem as a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the TCP Listener being in a Thread in it's own, so the asynchronous call did not block the main thread but the listeners thread.
We solved this issue by forcing the counter in a explicit Attending Time Counter Thread and marked the shared methods of both threads as *scope_locked* to prevent dual-access related problems.

```
boost::mutex m;
void method(datapacket& data)
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock l(m);
    [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the doc:

> Behaves the same as async(std::launch::async | std::launch::deferred, f, args...). In other words, f may be executed in another thread or it may be run synchronously when the resulting std::future is queried for a value.

Are you querying the resulting `std::future` anytime earlier than the asynchronous dispatch?

Comment: I don't have a result, I just want it to wait for x-seconds without blocking the rest of the program and then do things. Is my initial start with std::async wrong?

Comment: So, as per your edits, probably this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804683/delayed-function-call

Comment: It's not working, too. It still blocks the other server functionality. I think my initial function call is not asynchronous. If I call `std::async (scoreAttendance, p);
std::cout << "Login done" << std::endl;` it will print the cout after all the things done in the async call are finished.